# Function for resend email takes me to the home page and does nothing in the given function - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have this simple function on click to send email to the users if the first one after registration didnt go. But when i click on the button it doesn nothing and takes me to the home page.

**The resend function:**

```
protected function resend()
    {
        $user = Account::where('email', Auth::user()->email)->first();
        $user->verifyToken = Str::random(40);
        $user->save();

        $this->sendEmail($user);
        return redirect(route('verifyEmail'))->with('user',$user)->with('success', 'A link has been sent to your email');

    }
```

`Route::post('/resend/email', 'Auth\RegisterController@resend')->name('resendEmail');`

**The html:**

```
<form action=" {!! route('resendEmail') !!}" method="POST">
   @csrf
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">Resend Verification Link</button>
</form>
```

**Middleware problem fixed by adding to the constructor:**
`$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['resendEmail']]);`

Comment: maybe because of the leading `/` before resend in the route? try `Route::post('resend/email',...`

Comment: but `return redirect(route('verifyEmail'))->with('user',$user)->with('success', 'A link has been sent to your email');` shouldnt this return to the given route?

Comment: it's not probably hitting the function. you can dd something in the function to confirm.

Comment: hmm, yes the dd does not show up

Comment: what could i check to see whats wrong?

Comment: Change route as mentioned in the first comment, and see if it works.

Comment: Did you delete `Auth::routes();` from route?

Comment: @user3532758 the '/' route is after the resend route

Comment: @STA not its at the bottom of the web.php

Comment: Delete it to check,  and try this

Comment: @user3532758 also your first comment is not complete, the "Try (then the route)" ends in few words

Comment: I meant to change this route like so: `Route::post('resend/email', 'Auth\RegisterController@resend')->name('resendEmail');` but as STA said delete auth and check

Comment: i deleted it but still same, redirects me to the home page. i deleted the "/" as you said in the route post but nah.

Comment: Replace resend route with: `Route::post('resend/email', 'Auth\RegisterController@resend')->name('resendEmail');` and see if it works. Deleted the leading slash

Comment: still nothing...

Comment: make function public and try

Comment: still nothing, its like some hole in other controller or function that makes this..

Comment: can you share the route file?

Comment: i added it to the question above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217907/discussion-between-user3532758-and-yami-nooh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this on `RegisterController` *__construct* method :

```
$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['account/security/resend/email']]);
```