# Why we have used except('logout')?

Tags: php, laravel, web, backend

In one of the training tutorials , I saw this code in LoginController but I don't understand why except('logout') is used.

[image: 1]

Could you please explain it to a beginner?
What does except('logout') mean?
I understand that something is excluded from the selection  but I can't for some reasonю

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is middleware?
I will explain it a little bit different.
Let's say you want to enter into a room, but before that, you need to unlock the door and enter inside the room. The door is your middleware, you need to successfully unlock the door to enter inside the room. If you can't unlock the door, your access will be forbidden. What is it mean `except` word. You have two rooms one with a door and one without door, in this case `logout` is the room without door and you can access to her without any key or you don't need to unlock the door, for other one you need to successfully unlock the door and then go inside the room. I hope you understand, but if you have any questions, i will try to anser them. With **except** word you say attach this middleware to every route, and leave logout open, so if you try to access every other route, first your code will execute middleware and after that will execute your method, but for logout , you will execute lgout method directly without middleware

Comment: A really good explanation of what middleware is. But why in this case we use except("logout"). Sorry for my stupid questions, but I really red many tutorials but i still silly in middleware conception.

Comment: @Xeros whats happen if you make a custom logout option? here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/62919910/4575350

Comment: with except word you say attach this middleware to every route, and leave logout open, so if you try to access every other route, first your code will execute middleware and after that will execute your method, but for logout , you will execute lgout method directly without middleware

Comment: @sta A good example, there excluded resendEmail. However, I still don't understand yet...
In principle, I read the documentation and more or less understand Laravel, not quite stupid that is. However I don't have any thoughts here

Comment: @Xeros try to make a custom logout route,  you will see the magic.

Comment: @PlamenPenchev You're the best! Thank you very much. Everything is clear now.

Can I ask you a quick question as an experienced developer? I need to create multiauthorization, like there are a lot of tutorials on this material, but I don't have a separate page for authorization and authorization occurs as a pop-up window. Also, depending on the authentication (admin or boss), different content should appear on the main page. I know that you need to use Blade directives, but I can't find a good tutorial on this material.
Do you have anything in your stash about this?

Comment: you mean normal login with email password, and social authentication via facebook or google. 
if you need to load different content depends on user role, you can type something like this inside blade `@if (Auth::user()->type === 'admin') <li><A href="{{route('admin.panel')}}>Admin panel</a></li>" @endif` and this anchor will be shown only if the user is admin

Comment: @PlamenPenchev Good idea, I didn't know, thank you for your supporting!!!

To be honest, I'm already confused. This does not mean that I am lazy, I watch tutorials, and there is about the same thing. Reading the documentation doesn't help either.
In desperation, I created a new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124129/how-to-use-the-blade-directive-when-made-a-multiauth-admins-bosses
It will be cool if you take part :)

Comment: I leaved a reply to your new question, please read it. I explained how to create middleware for your user role and how to separate user roles