# How to use the Blade-Directive when made a multiauth (admins + bosses)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I reviewed all tutorials on multiauth (without using is_admin) with different tables for different levels of authorization. I have two authorization entities: boss and admin (Manager and admin)

However, unlike all these tutorials:

1. I don't have a separate authorization page. The authorization window is located on the main page and appears when you click on the authorization icon (using JS, just display:block)
2. All these tutorials have separate authorization pages for different roles (separately for the Manager and separately for the admin). I have one authorization window, so I need to authenticate the user on one window (for two roles at once: admin and Manager)
3. There is no use of blade directives in any tutorial (I've already looked through all sorts of tutorials). Just unique for each content I have is contained directly on the main page (I do not have a separate admin panel and personal account Manager). What should I do in this case? To write a custom Directive? Does Laravel have something ready out of the box?

Sorry for so many questions, I just have nowhere to turn, there is really nothing left on the Internet (maybe I can't find it)

The most useful thing I could find (of all the tutorials, including youtube-video tutorials of course):

- https://www.codermen.com/blog/123/how-to-make-multi-auth-in-laravel-6
- https://www.siddharthshukla.in/blog/how-to-use-multiple-authentication-guards-in-laravel-6-app/
  --> I made my own authentication using this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need separate login pages for different user roles. you need one.
if you have user table like this

```
id type   name   email ...
1  admin  Plamen Penchev
2  boss   Ivan   Ivanov
```

after user logged in successfully you will use this user type to load different content depends on user role
Let's look for a example from one of my projects

```
@if (Auth::user())
   <ul class="login-register profile-details">
       <li>
           <a href="{{route('user.profile')}}">
             <img src="{{asset(Auth::user()->image)}}" />{{Auth::user()->name}}
            </a>
       </li>
        <li class="user_points">
            <p>{{Auth::user()->points}} Points</p>
       </li>
    @if (Auth::user()->type === 'admin)
        <li> <a href="#">ADmin Panel</a></li>
    @endif // you can check the same way for boss 
    </ul>
    @else
    <ul class="login-register">
         <li><a class="popup-text" href="{{route('auth.login')}}" data-effect="mfp-move-from-top"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Sign in</a>
         </li>
         <li><a class="popup-text" href="{{route('auth.register')}}" data-effect="mfp-move-from-top"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Sign up</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
    @endif
```

after that you need to create a middleware and attach this middlewares for the routes that must be access it only from certain user role

How to create a middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckAdmin
```

step 2 type code like this inside your middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->type ===  'admin') {
            return $next($request);
     }

    return redirect('/');
    }
```

step 3 register your middleware
open `app/Kernel.php` and find `protected $routeMiddleware` array
and declare your middleware

```
'check.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdmin::class,
```

Now you can attach your middleware  to routes like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin, 'middleware'  => 'check.admin'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index)->name('admin.index');
})
```

You can create different middlewares for every userrole you have.

About authentication
You need only one login form, validate it with Request helpers and after that login user to his account and depends on user role you will restrict pages, content and everything

Also you can read more about blade directives [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade) LAravel documentation is very clear and easy to understand

Comment: Thank you for your experience and examples. This is a very good leap for me.
As for the documentation, Yes, it is well written, but it doesn't solve my problems. I read it every day and learn something new, but I don't go forward

https://imgur.com/a/msfJma9 ---> my all tables in web-site
Unfortunately, I don't have a role. I have completely different tables (supervisor(this is boss) and admins). Could you tell me what to do in this case?

Comment: let's say I'am supervisor and want to see only projects that are under me, right?

Comment: A little wrong, there is a separate page for displaying this (supervisor's projects).
However, I have a home page where I need to connect three roles. The administrator displays its own logo, and the supervisor displays its own logo. The supervisor has the right to add the project administrator has no such ability.I hve maketsin Figma (can translate in Photoshop).

Comment: Give at least a .rough estimate of how I can do this. I can,of course, pay you for a small consultation, but I am a poor student from Russia, so I don't have more than 10$ in my pocket, to be honest.

Comment: if you have skype, add me, search for my name with the same picture, and we can discuss it, but currently I'm at work, and can talk after 2 hours

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added. I'm not sure if it's you, because it's a slightly different photo

Comment: live:.cid.ac16b2a0f06b3f2e --> skypeLogin
Xeros --> skypeName

I can't find you. Maybe a lot of people live in Bulgaria with your name (is it a very common name?). I already wrote to two of them and they wrote "Не ви познавам"

Comment: :D ok , type syncmaster994 that's  me